# Relative file path issue while using Apache rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path, apache

I am trying to create some Apache rewrite rules that shall be able to route URI requests like e.g.

`http://mydomain.com/articles/example` to
`http://mydomain.com/index.php?site=articles&page=example`

What I've got so far is this:

`RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).html$ index.php?site=$1&page=$2 [L]`
`RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?site=$1&page=$2 [L]`

Since I am using relative file paths everywhere in my index.php, for style sheets, scripts, images and the like, I am facing the problem of incorrectly resolved absolute file paths.

For example when I am in the root, `http://mydomain.com/` or `http://mydomain.com/articles`, all relative image paths resolve correctly - `images/logo.jpg` becomes `http://mydomain.com/images/logo.jpg` or `htdocs/mydomain/images/logo.jpg` respectively.

When I click one of my links on the site, e.g. `http://mydomain.com/articles/example`, Apache (or the Browser?) assumes all my images are located here `http://mydomain.com/articles/images/` - it is pretty obvious that this path doesn't really exist.

So here are my questions:

**1.** Is it possible to solve this problem **without** changing all my relative file paths to absolute ones?

I could use root `/` for all my paths on my actual web server, because my domain is advantageously linked.
`mydomain.com` is linked to `/html/mydomain` on my web server - `/` resolves to `mydomain.com/`, but on my personal computer I am running XAMPP and `/` resolves to `htdocs/` - it should however resolve to `htdocs/mydomain/` simply because I hold several sites in `htdocs`

Absolute file paths are terrible when updating index.php to my web server, because I have to auto-systematically replace path declarations - not only in index.php, but style sheets and scripts as well.

**2.** Should I create a static DNS entry on my personal computer to adapt to my web server?

**3.** What is the most commonly used method?

Thank you in advance!

Sincerely, Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by myself, by editing Windows' `hosts` file and the Apache's `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

**1.** Adding a new static DNS entry to `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

`127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.local`

**2.** Appending a new virtual host entry to `%ApacheInstallDir%\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

`<Directory "E:\htdocs">`
`Order Deny,Allow`
`Allow from all`
`</Directory>`

`NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1`

`<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>`
`DocumentRoot "E:\htdocs"`
`ServerName localhost`
`</VirtualHost>`

`<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>`
`DocumentRoot "E:\htdocs\mydomain"`
`ServerName www.mydomain.local`
`</VirtualHost>`

Now `http://www.mydomain.local` leads to `htdocs/mydomain` directly

**3.** Changing all relative paths and links in my index.php by simply "rooting" them with a `/` in front of them, e.g. `<img src="/images/logo.jpg" />`

I also managed to set up a Site in Dreamweaver, so I am able to use the Design- and the Live-View correctly.